# Angular routing is only working sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Right now I have four components within my Angular project: home, portfolio, contact, and about. When I am on the home page I can navigate to any of the other component through my nav-bar. However, when I am on any of the other pages I can only navigate to the home page.

[image]

This picture is an example of when I am on any component other than the home page. It is trying to navigate to the about router-link within the portfolio component. But obviously that does not exist because that is in the app-component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '' , component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my app-routing.module.ts

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-trans">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img height="250" src="assets/Kaan-Logo-PNG.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
                <div class="pull-xs-right justify-content-end" id="navbarToggler-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mt-2 mt-md-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

then this is my portfolio.component.html

Comment: Can you post your routes and some HTML where the navigation isn't working

Comment: It's very hard to debug code when you cannot see it.

Comment: alright I think I added what you would need

Comment: your routerlink should start with a slash `routerLink="/portfolio"`

Comment: @Hareesh thank you I was struggling with this for some time, that worked

Answer (score 1):

Try adding / to your routerLink entries like **routerLink="/about"**

Answer (score 1):

Update portfolio.component.html like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-trans">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img height="250" src="assets/Kaan-Logo-PNG.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
                <div class="pull-xs-right justify-content-end" id="navbarToggler-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mt-2 mt-md-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```